# Octave's 'system' does not interpret a escape sequence

Tags: printf, system, octave

When executing this command from the prompt or from a script

`system ("printf ""\\x1B[32mword\\x1B[0m\n""");`

it will print this text

`\x1B[32mword\x1B[0m`

instead of interpreting the escape sequence for the `printf` linux command. Octave's `unix` will raise the same output.

The very same command is interpreted correctly from the Linux terminal's prompt, printing 'word' in green.

How to make it interpret the color escape sequence, instead of raw text?

Running on GNU Octave Version 3.6.1.

**Update:** It seems that Octave does not support these escape sequences ([link](http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?39774)), even if the GNU pages define it ([link](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Escape-Sequences-in-String-Constants.html)). The correct command would be

`system ("printf ""\x1B[32mejemplo\x1B[0m\n""");`

and its output

`warning: unrecognized escape sequence \x' -- converting to x'
 warning: unrecognized escape sequence \x' -- converting to x'
 x1B[32mejemplox1B[0m`

**Update:** In the meanwhile, I've solved the problem with this bash script, which can certainly be invoked with a `system` call.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# formatted output
#   arguments:
#
#     Text attributes
#     0 All attributes off
#     1 Bold on
#     4 Underscore (on monochrome display adapter only)
#     5 Blink on
#     7 Reverse video on
#     8 Concealed on
#     
#     Foreground colors
#     30 Black
#     31 Red
#     32 Green
#     33 Yellow
#     34 Blue
#     35 Magenta
#     36 Cyan
#     37 White
#     
#     Background colors
#     40 Black
#     41 Red
#     42 Green
#     43 Yellow
#     44 Blue
#     45 Magenta
#     46 Cyan
#     47 White

if [[ "$#" -ne 4 ]]; then
  echo "cprintf (bash): wrong number of parameters."
  exit 1
fi

printf "\x1b[%d;%d;%dm%s\x1b[0m" $1 $2 $3 $4
```

Comment: Both your command and this one `system('printf "\\x1B[32mword\\x1B[0m\n"');` yield a green word here. This is with octave 3.8.2 on linux. Is my version working better for you ?

Comment: Same error for me: `\x1B[32mword\x1B[0m`.  Packages were uninstalled in my Octave installation, could it be that escape sequences are processed somewhere there?

Comment: What shell is Octave running?  Run `system('echo $SHELL')` to find out.

Comment: @nightcod3r With single quotes strings are not interpreted by octave, this is why now the error is different. Then the antislash appear because they are escaped (doubled). Please try `system('bash -c printf "\x1B[32mword\x1B[0m\n"');`

Comment: @Rufflewind :  it is /bin/bash

Comment: @huntj : it doesn't seem to understand the command, the result is `printf: usage: printf [-v var] format [arguments]`

Comment: @nightcod3r Sorry, wrong copy/paste. This one should be better. `system('bash -c ''printf "\x1B[32mword\x1B[0m\n"''');`

Comment: @nightcod3r And if your shell is really bash, then `system('printf "\x1B[32mword\x1B[0m\n"');` should be fine also.

Comment: @huntj This works nicely!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Octave [interprets double quoted strings](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Escape-Sequences-in-String-Constants.html). And your octave version does not understand `\x`.
The solution is to use single quote character, since

> In single-quoted strings, backslash is not a special character

And let bash handle the color escape sequence:

```
system('bash -c ''printf "\x1B[32mword\x1B[0m\n"''');
```

Repeated single quotes are needed so that the command launched by system is

```
bash -c 'printf "\x1B[32mword\x1B[0m\n"'
```

This executes the `printf "\x1B[32mword\x1B[0m\n"` command inside a new `bash` shell.
And the escape characters in the string between double quotes are correctly interpreted.

As a side note, with octave 3.8.2 on linux you could just issue

```
system('printf "\x1B[32mword\x1B[0m\n"');
```

or even

```
printf "\x1B[32mword\x1B[0m\n"
```

Comment: What does work for me is the bash-mediated solution (`system('bash -c ''printf "\x1B[32mword\x1B[0m\n"''');`), not the one in the answer. Please, correct this.

Comment: @nightcod3r Your comment "this works nicely" was not related to my last comment ? Anyway, answer updated. What happen if you issue `printf "\x1B[32mword\x1B[0m\n"` directly in a bash shell ?

Comment: yep, this is a problem here, you can't comment on a concrete comment. this is what worked: `system('bash -c printf "\x1B[32mword\x1B[0m\n"')`. as for the shell command, that works as well.

Comment: @nightcod3r For a printf in color, here is a new [cprintf](http://sourceforge.net/p/cprintf-m/code) function. Just issue `cprintf("green", "word\n")`. And for more, `demo cprintf`

Comment: Nice @ederag, it works just fine. Looks like you're always there... ;) Thx!!

Comment: Hi @ederag, would love to learn your programming style. I can see in your script how clean and organized is everything. Is there any guide, or tips, that you could share with us?

Comment: @nightcod3r The [zen of python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) is a fine collection of general programming tips. For octave, there are some [guidelines](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Octave-Sources-_0028m_002dfiles_0029.html), although I comply to all of them only for contributions to octave itself.

Comment: Thanks, #ederag, but it looks like you are importing other sources. (You don't use the parenthesis for `if` conditions, and the `case`s aligned with the `switch` statement... - were you simply applying 'Beautiful is better than ugly' here?).

Comment: Any hint on how to upgrade `cprintf` such that also the background color can be controlled?, now it's only the ink that we can specify. Thx.

Comment: So, the `cprintf` question seems to be still alive: I'm using it in schools, color is indeed important here, so children can easily segment the message, but the distro is based on Ubuntu 12.04, so the Octave version included is 3.2.4. It seems that the `printf` command is not interpreting well these escape sequences, and when the error has been reported, they say that there's nothing they can do for such an old version. I would be very thankful if you could provide me with hints as to how to make it work. (PS: Octave upgrading is not possible for administrative reasons).

Comment: And while I was writing this message somebody was digging into the problem, it looks like `cprintf` can easily be made backward compatible. (Find the hint in the bug report previously attached.)

Comment: Rewritting `"\033[01;"` by `strcat(char(base2dec("033",8)),"[01;")`, and `"\033[00m;"` by `strcat(char(base2dec("033",8)),"[00m")` (if the octal notation is to be preserved), or alternatively, `strcat(char(27),"[01;")` and `strcat(char(27),"[00m")` (in decimal notation) will just make it.

Comment: @nightcod3r, [updated](https://sourceforge.net/p/cprintf-m/code/ci/default/tree/cprintf.m).